# How to get gerrit URL after git upload using gitpython?

Tags: git, gerrit, gitpython

```
repo=Repo.clone_from(my_repo,'/path/to/clone')
git=repo.git
#cd to repo and do some update to my_file
git.add([my_file])
git.commit("My commit message")
#Upload to gerrit
git.push("origin","HEAD:refs/for/master")
```

This works, I followed [gitPython](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) doc, but not sure how to get the gerrit number after upload, I need to do developer-verified on the same, git.push just returning an empty string.

Blockquote

Comment: What specifically are you looking for?  The remote repository URL? The gerrit change URL? Something else?  Please update your question to show exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `with_extended_output=True` in `git.push()` and use a tuple `(status, stdout, stderr)` to get the output.

```
status,out,err = git.push("origin","HEAD:refs/for/master",with_extended_output=True)
```

The number and the url can be found in `err` if `status == 0`. `err` is a string and you need to parse it to get the exact number.

`with_extended_output` is `False` by default. It applies to all `git.xxx()` methods. These methods invoke [execute](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=with_extended_output#git.cmd.Git.execute). For more details, see the link.